# How to find the source code of a CssClass in Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, webforms, aspxgridview

How can I trace back to look at the table table-striped css code?

Comment: `ctrl` + `shift` + `f`, then type in the css class?

Comment: or, ctr + shift + c in browser and move you pointer to the element using CssClass, css source will display in the right sight at the Styles tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find anything in your solution you can do so by using the search functionality in VS. It's impossible to do anything without it, definitely one of the most used shortcuts.

Opens the window to search the entire solution for whatever it is you're after...

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can use <CTRL><SHIFT><F> to find the CSS class. I prefer to use this in conjunction with Dev Tools and the Elements selector.

One other thing, I see you're using a GridView. If you're working on a responsive website, a GridView will not work since it produces its own table markup. If that Is the case I would suggest using a ListView instead, especially if you're hooking up to Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you very much